# Trigger addEventListener on live element that is not in the DOM (native JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with my modal popup plugin since a week.
I'll try to explain as much as i can but first, here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hideo/yth37hhf/27/

I know the code contains some other functions but they are useful for my plugin.

So, my issue is that the function "triggerLinkAction" contains an addEventListener which is not fired.

```
(function() {
    Window.prototype.triggerLinkAction = function(){
        var triggeredLink = document.getElementById("triggeredOtherAction");
        var inputTarget = document.getElementById("inputText");
        console.log('triggeredLink',triggeredLink);
        triggeredLink.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            alert('If this pops out, I will be very happy!!!');
            e.preventDefault();
            inputTarget.value = "This text should be on the input field...";
        }, true);
    }
})();
```

The targeted element is inside the modal, and this modal is displayed by clicking on the link "A small modal".
When the plugin calls *ShowModal()*, I trigger the *TransitionEnd* event to call a function

```
[.... code ...]

function ShowModal() {
    vars.popupContainer.classList.add("show");
    hsdk.PrefixedEvent(vars.popupOverlay, "TransitionEnd", function (e) {
        executeFunctions();
    });
}

[.... code ...]
```

The *executeFunctions()* will check which functions need to be called:

```
[.... code ...]
function executeFunctions() {
    if (vars.opts && vars.opts.fn) {
        var allFunctions = vars.opts.fn.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < allFunctions.length; i++)
        {
            var functionName = allFunctions[i];
            var functionToExecute = window[functionName];
            if(typeof functionToExecute === 'function') {
                functionToExecute();
            }
        }
    }
}

[.... code ...]
```

There are some comments on the javascript part about the plugin, but feel free to ask if I can provide any other information.

PS: I don't care about IE for now ;-)

Comment: Where does `triggerLinkAction()` get called?

Comment: I guess you've read [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

Comment: I do not understand your question fully, but my guess is you want to use Event delegation.

Comment: copying innerHTML of `<div id="testInnerModal"` means you'll have **two** elements with **id** = **triggeredOtherAction** - this makes javascript a sad panda - in other words, don't do that, things break - p.s. you can do `window.triggerLinkAction` instead of `Window.prototype.triggerLinkAction`

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: in "executeFunction()". I'm looping on each _fn_ parameters, which are on data-option of the link.
And I invoke methods with _window[functionName]_

Comment: @JaromandaX: Ohh sh**... I didn't see that.. I'll check if this fixes my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @RobG: I didn't read this article but I will. Looks a very helpful article too. Thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX: The issue was having **two IDs**!! And I'll also change with `window.triggerLinkAction` too. You've really saved my day!

Comment: fix the extending DOM issue like I suggested too - I think it will still work

Comment: I didn't fix the extending DOM issue yet (I will) but I now have a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/hideo/yth37hhf/30/. Thank you all very much!